# How to hide/hidden Lightning page tab banner from lightning app page

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have one Lightning Page Tab, which is link with my VFP and LWC component.I need to hide the Page Banner in the Lightning App Page.
This is Lightning page tab not a lightning component Tab.
So please help me to give some solution on it.

[image: Lightning page Tab]

I try to create new tab but it give me same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Static Resource solution updated to work with Summer '21 Release.

New Version

```
[app_flexipage-header_header-host]{
    display:none;
}
```

Old Version

```
header.flexipageHeader.slds-page-header.uiBlock.oneAnchorHeader { 
    display: none;
}
```

Create a static resource and add above code in that and import and use the static resource in your custm LWC component, ofcourse you will need to add that custom LWC component in you Custom Flexi page.